# Setting a type reference type to null doesn't affect copied type?

Tags: c#, .net, reference-type

Why does this produce "0" ?

```
object a = 0;
object b = a;
a = null;
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString()); // Produces "0"
Console.Read();
```

Doesn't b point to the same location and setting a = null effectively makes b null?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Setting `a = null` removes `a`'s reference (the arrow) to the object (the boxed integer `0`). It does not affect the object itself. `b` still references the unchanged object afterwards.

Comment: So no matter how "a" is defined, it will never be more than a reference to "some object"? Or is there no way to set up "a", so that when we do "a=null", "some object" also gets set to null?

Comment: You can choose between using reference types or value types. Nullable value types in this case. Primitive types like `int` or `double` and structs are value types. A variable of a value type contains the "object" itself. If you set an `int?` (same as `Nullable<int>`) variable to `null` then this "object" is null; however, you cannot have two variables be the same "object". An assignment of a value type (e.g. `int? b = a;`) always creates a copy of this object, unless you assign it to a reference type (like `System.Object`), then it will be boxed inside a newly created reference type object.

Comment: Thanks again. So you are saying that if both a and b are declare as System.Object, then they are (and both represent) "some object"? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: When you assign one variable to another, you always copy a value. It just happens that in case of a reference type, this value is a reference. Boxing is a special case. See: [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

Comment: Another question for you :-) Is there a way to box an object using delegates? I am having a bit of a problem in a scenario where my object is composed of properties which are also objects. The latter needs to be passed around and modified

Comment: Boxing any applies only to value types. When a value type is assigned to a reference type variable (a class or an interface), then a new (reference type ) object is created as a wrapper for this value. C# does this automatically for you.

Comment: Any chance we could take that offline? I am stuggling on a problem and don't want to pollute this page with comments. Maybe you can help :-)

Comment: Ask a new question SO.

Comment: Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64442990/returning-a-reference-of-a-class-property-that-is-strongly-typed

Answer (score 22):

You want to know where the cookies are. You have a piece of paper, labelled "A". On the paper is written in pencil "123 Sesame Street".

The paper is not a cookie. The address is not a cookie. The paper contains a reference to an address which contains the cookie.

You obtain a second piece of paper, labelled "B". On that piece of paper, you make a *copy* of the contents of "A". Now you have two pieces of paper, both say "123 Sesame Street". Both tell you where the cookies are.

You take piece of paper "A" and erase it.  "A" no longer refers to the location of the cookies. **B still does.**

You are assuming that saying "b = a" means to write on B "for the location of the cookies, please consult paper A".  But that is not what "b = a" means in C#; it means *make a copy of the reference*, not *make an alias of the reference*.

In C# to make an alias of the reference you use the "ref" keyword, confusingly enough:

```
void M(ref object b)
{
    b = null;
}
...
object a = 0;
M(ref a);
// "b" now becomes an alias for "a"; when "b" is nulled out, so is "a" because they are the same variable with two different names.
```

In C# you can only do this when calling a method that takes a ref parameter like this. The feature you want is not supported in C#, though we have considered supporting it:

```
object a = 0;
ref object b = ref a;
a = null; // b and a are aliases for the same variable now.
```

Do you have a compelling need for this feature? If you do, please let me know what it is. That will help us prioritize whether or not the feature is worth doing in a hypothetical future version of C#.

UPDATE: It got done!  This feature was added to C# 7.

Comment: I'm not sure that the OP is assuming that "b = a" means "for the location of the cookies, please consult paper A".  I read the post as assuming that "a = null" means "remove the cookies from the location on paper A".

Comment: I have a question, after setting "a" to NULL, will there still be an entry in the stack named "a" with an empty value, or does setting it to NULL mean directly deleting the entry from the stack?

Comment: @TamerM: Setting a variable to null does not "delete" the variable; what if you tried to say `if (a==null)` later?

Comment: Starting with C# 7.0 we have [ref returns and ref locals](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-ref-returns-and-locals)!

Answer (score 6):

You are setting the *reference* to null, **you are not changing the object the reference points to**.
`a` and `b` are two separate references, hence setting `a` to `null` will of course leave `b` unchanged (Think "pointer"), it just means that a now points to `null` ("nowhere").

Answer (score 3):

Boxing (which is the process that happens here) is pretty nicely explained in the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) with examples at what happens in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a description of what's going on:

```
object a = 0; // pointer a = 0xSomeA
object b = a; // pointer b = 0xSomeB
a = null; // nulling a, now 0x00; b still the same
```