# Replace Java object instance with another and all references

Tags: java, object

is there a way to replace an object in java with another one that updates all references to the first one to instead point to the second one? In C# this question was answered here: [Replace object instance with another in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377329/replace-object-instance-with-another-in-c-sharp) but I was wondering if I could do this in Java. Thanks!

EDIT: 1. I want to replace the first object with a an object of a subtype. 2. I can't edit the implementation of the first object, that's why I'm replacing it with a subtype. I can edit the subtype.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? What is the scenario?

Comment: It's about modding games. I want to replace an instance of a class to a subclass that has extra functionality, that way by not modifying the base class I promote compatibility.

Comment: Well note that the C# approach you reference would not let you do that, either. In there, the older object's state is completely overwritten with that of the newer object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't don't this, even if you can.  Instead, use another class to contain or wrap the object you want to replace.  The container has to implement all the methods you need from the original by calling the methods in the original, but you can replace the wrapped class easily at any time.  The wrapper, the original class, and the one you replace it with should all implement the same interface.  This solution's a bit of work, but it will hold up over time.

I suspect what you really want is a class that has a number of upgradable component parts, but this will do for starters, and get you thinking the right way.

Comment: He doesn't want to change the referers' implementation or the original instance's implementation.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga I'm fine changing the new implementation, just not the original.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga: Nothing really changes here.  Everything references the wrapper, which is like a pointer to the class that makes it work.  Swap class B for class A inside the container and now the container (class C, say) looks like B instead of class A to everything.  This is something like "dependency injection".  If A, B, and C all implement the same interface, that's polymorphism.  Whenever I want to swap classes in the middle of something, I do this.  I usually come up with a better solution before I'm done, but this get's me started.

Comment: @RalphChapin, in order to use this technique, all the existing classes that used to use `A` needs to now use the wrapper.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga: Yes.  Or better yet, the interface.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent was to replace *all* instances of a particular type with a subtype, then you can consider using [java agents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

Using this, you would replace the base class with your enhanced class during classloading.