# Replace duplicate java objects including all references

Tags: java, object, reference

I know we already had questions about the [replacement of object instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116431/replace-java-object-instance-with-another-and-all-references), and the answer was always: even if you can, never do it, it's dark magic, but I am not sure how to solve my problem, so let me explain...

I'm parsing data about certain vehicles and their specific modules to store in a database (it's about a game). Each `Vehicle` has among other data a number of `ComaptibleModules`:

```
class Vehicle {
    String id;
    // other stuff...
    CompatibleModules modules;
}
```

`ComaptibleModules` contains lots of objects descending of the `Module`-class (e.g. `Engine extends Module`) in a complex arragement (dependencies and stuff).

```
class CompatibleModules {
    Engine defaultEngine;
    List<Engine> compatibleEngines;
    // other stuff...
}
```

It is to be expected that the same `Module` is referenced multiple times in this class.

I'm only getting the data on a per-vehicle basis, so even if some vehicles share the same modules (which they do, excessively), I'm writing a new `Module` object for each vehicle. After I'm done with parsing, I want to optimize the database by removing the duplicates and storing the Modules separately, so the vehicles do only reference the modules by ID.

And that's where the problem starts: I can easily get all the `Module`s out of the `CompatibleModules`-structure of each `Vehicle`, store them in a `HashSet` and thereby detect collisions. But after I've detected a collision, it is not a trivial task to replace all references of the duplicate in the `CompatibleModules` with the original one.

What would be an elegant way to replace all references of the duplicates in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Stop thinking of modules as parts of your vehicles, think of them as independent parts that you use to build vehicles.

So you want to have a factory that manages the available modules and when you build vehicles, you ask the factory for the necessary modules. The factory then makes sure that each module "type" or "instance" exists only once in the whole system.

**[EDIT]** One solution would be to replace `List<Engine> compatibleEngines` with `Set<Engine> compatibleEngines = new LinkedHashSet<>();`. `LinkedHashSet` preserves insert order. After this change, you can simply add modules and they will overwrite each other.

Note: For this to work properly, you must overwrite `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

If you can't do this, then create a wrapper object that has a good `equals()` and `hashCode()`. To clean the duplicates:

```
Set<Wrapper> wrappedEngines = new LinkedHashSet<>();    
for( Engine e : compatibleEngines ) {
    wrappedEngines.add( new Wrapper( e ) );
}
compatibleEngines.clear();
for( Wrapper e : wrappedEngines ) {
    compatibleEngines.add( e.getDelegate() );
}
```

Comment: OK, but this is not about creating ingame verhicles with a factory, it's about a database containing all the vehicle and module data - without duplicates. So in the end I want to export it to XML or SQL or whatever...

Comment: If the modules are distinct in the database where do you get duplicates?

Comment: The data I get is not perfect and contains duplicates. I parse what I get and store it in a reasonable object structure. Then I start taking care of the duplicates and other imperfections...
I could already consider the elimination of duplicates while the sources are being parsed, but I'd rather do that afterwards; it's not the job of a parser.

Comment: You should write a DB cleanup job and remove the duplicates at the source.

Comment: Sorry, I have only read-access to the source. The program I'm writing _is_ the DB cleanup job, or rather, it converts a lot of loosely coupled data into a single clean database.

Comment: Tanks for the update. Yeah, the `LinkedHashSet` prevents duplicates within it's own datastructure, and I do provide `equals()` and `hashCode()` on all `Module`s, but sadly that's not enough: There may be duplicates in other objects or collections within the `CompatibleModules` of this or another vehicle, so there's no way around some kind of collection outside the scope of a single vehicle.

Comment: In that case, I suggest to forget the ORM approach. It's pure overhead in your case. Write a tool that can follow foreign key relations and clean the database using SQL scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my ugly solution. I don't like it, but it does the job. Still, it's not the answer to my question, just the solution for this specific problem...

```
void bruteForce(List<CompatibleModules> compatibles) {
    for (CompatibleModules c : compatibles) {
        c.defaultEngine = replaceDuplicate(c.defaultEngine);
        replaceDuplicates(c.compatibleEngines);
        // TODO: add all other fields of CompatibleModules here...
    }
}

/** Mapping: Module ID -> Module */
protected Map<String, Module> moduleMap = new HashMap<String, Module>();

protected <M extends Module> M replaceDuplicate(M m) {
    String id = m.getID();

    Module stored = moduleMap.get(id);
    if(stored != null) {
        return (M) stored;
    } else {
        moduleMap.put(id, m);
        return m;
    }
}

protected <M extends Module> List<M> replaceDuplicates(List<M> modules) {
    for (int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++) {
        M m = modules.get(i);
        M r = replaceDuplicate(m);
        if(r != m) {
            modules.remove(i);
            modules.add(i, r);
        }
    }
    return modules;
}
```

I'm using this strange `<M extends Module>`-Pattern to make `replaceDuplicates` accept Lists of all `Module` subclasses, which is just workaround for a flaw in the design of Java's generics.