# passing pointers to linked list using java. But when I modify the data in the memory/Array it's not updated in the Linked List. Why?

Tags: java, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I am new in JAVA. I am trying to make couple of linked lists. All holding pointer/reference to some array element. Therefore, if I make any change in the array, it should reflect in the linked list. Right?
In my program, the modification shows in the array, but the lists value are the same. (I deleted one element. it's not in the array anymore. but the linked list is still showing it)

I am passing references to linked list. if that works, why the modification is not working?
Looks like the linked lists have their own copy of data. But, that is not how reference work.

Any explanation? Suggestion what else can be used to show the memory dependency?

Comment: They don't. Show me your code and I'll tell you what's going on

Comment: Java only supports pass by value.  References are passed by value.

Comment: I made the array using ArrayList<String>WM=new ArrayList<>. then I put some values manually using WM.add(string). created 2 lists first, second using LinkedList<String> and put the pointers like this: first.add(WM.get(0)), second.add(WM.get(0)). then i deleted WM[0]. it shows. but first and second are unaffected. Any suggestion, how can I implement this? ALL I WANT to show is a Common memory. a center of sharing. looks like lists are building their own copies. Suggestion?

Comment: "looks like lists are building their own copies." - They are but they are building a copy of the reference. Java is pass-by-value, when we deal with objects that value happens to be the value of the reference to the object. See http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html.

Comment: I have switched Linked List with simple arrays. then pass the reference the same way. Answer was same. Arrays are sticking to their old values. How can I achieve call by reference? so that, everybody will be using/editing/updating the same object/array element?

Answer (score 1):

I've commented above but I think your response warrants an answer.

> I made the array using ArrayListWM=new ArrayList<>. then I put some values manually using WM.add(string). created 2 lists first, second using LinkedList and put the pointers like this: first.add(WM.get(0)), second.add(WM.get(0)). then i deleted WM[0]. it shows. but first and second are unaffected.

As I mentioned in the comments Java is pass-by-value. It just so happens that when you pass objects you pass the value of the reference to that object.

When you do `first.add(WM.get(0))` what happens is `WM.get(0)` gets evaluated and returns the reference. Then this reference is passed-by-value to `first.add` so now we have two references to your original object. Now when you 'delete' the value at WM[0] what you are actually doing is removing one reference to the original object. The other references stay intact.

> How can I achieve call by reference? so that, everybody will be using/editing/updating the same object/array element?

For using and updating an object (mutating it's state by calling method on it) what you have is perfectly fine. If by update you mean replace all references of an object with references to another object then this goes against the point of Java's reference system. To quote an answer to a similar question; [Don't don't this, even if you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116431)

Ultimately, what problem are you trying to solve? You've said you are new to Java, it might just be a case of learning the idiomatic Java approach to solve the problem rather than trying to use an approach you're familiar with.

Comment: THANKS! I finally understand the idea "As I mentioned in the comments Java is pass-by-value. It just so happens that when you pass objects you pass the value of the reference to that object.". by deleting an element from WM I was only changing WM. not others. I changed the code. make a new class for the data and put that class's object to the Array and make the lists to point the array. updating value to the 'actual' object through its methods. it shows, what I wanted to learn.

Comment: Trying to implement a 'Baby version' of Rete algorithm. where my lists are rules. getting values from WM. lists share common data elements. that's why I make them pointing to the source, so that, when ever it updates, all the rules sharing it updates as well.

Comment: I am new (a week old) in JAVA. it has some libraries that will make my life easier. comparing it will C++ and passing by reference issue came up.

Answer (score 0):

"(I deleted one element. " you can't change the size of an array.

Based on what you are seeing most likely, if you deleted an element, you created a new array with one less element.  This is why the object in your LinkedList doesn't appear to have changed.

> first.add(WM.get(0)).

When you do this, it is the same as

```
Object referenceToObject = WM.get(0);
first.add(referenceToObject);

// removes the reference from WM.
WM.remove(0);
// this doesn't change referenceToObject or first
assert referenceToObject != null;
assert first.get(first.size() - 1) == referenceToObject;
```

But you can do this

```
// a reference to a reference.
AtomicReference<String> ref = new AtomicReference<>("Hello");

first.clear();
first.add(ref);

second.clear();
second.add(ref);

// all still there
assert first.get(0).get() == "Hello";
assert second.get(0).get() == "Hello";

// alter ref and all change
ref.set("World");
assert first.get(0).get() == "World";
assert second.get(0).get() == "World";

// or
ref.set(null);
assert first.get(0).get() == null;
assert second.get(0).get() == null;
```

Comment: Yes. Say WM is my array(created with ArrayList). is decreased by one element. but the linked lists (first, second) are holding the old values. I put the values this way: first.add(WM.get(0)). what I wanted to test, say, second.add(WM.get(0)) as well, if I delete WM.remove(position 0) it will affect the lists. they will lost the value or show null or something.  Arent they pointing to the same WM[0] ??

Comment: @Sharmin what you are thinking of is a reference to a reference to an object which Java doesn't support implicitly.  You can do something like this, see above.

Comment: @Sharmin I have added some examples of how you might do what you suggested.  I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: THANKS @Peter! So much to know! Apparently, I was thinking, my lists are pointing to the array elements. Whereas the array itself was pointing to an object. that's why the array was updating but the lists were not. So far, I have created a separate object for the value and assigning that value to WM and let the lists pointing to WM. (totally unnecessary but i had to see reference working). and it Works! finally they all are updating.

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor or method in [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) to specify the backing array. It sounds like you have an array and a LinkedList and are adding an object to the array and then adding the object to the LinkedList instance. Removing the object from the array does not remove it from the LinkedList in this scenario. Based on your description, you should be adding your object to the LinkedList instance and using that as your source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

Your linked list is not holding references to the "array element", but to the object referenced by the array.

```
// Create array
Person[] persons = new Person[2];
persons[0] = new Person("A");
persons[1] = new Person("B");

// Create linked list (of persons in reverse order)
LinkedList<Person> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(persons[1]);
list.add(persons[0]);
```

At this point, both `persons` (array) and `list` are referencing the two object (Person A and Person B). If you assign a new reference value to an array element, only the array is updated, not the list. However they both reference the same objects, so if you change the object, they both "see" it.

```
// Update array
persons[0] = new Person("C");

// Rename person B to B2
persons[1].setName("B2");

// Show content
System.out.println(persons[0] + ", " + persons[1]);
System.out.println(list);
```

Assuming `Person` has `toString()` implemented to return the name, this will be your output:

```
C, B2
[B2, A]
```

Comment: This what exactly happened. (well almost!). I made an array using ArrayList and put some strings using .add(). then I made 2 linked lists using LinkedList<String> (say first) and put the Array element index. EX: first.add(WM.get(0)). WM is the array. now, I am deleting one item and it's showing in WM. but it shows the whole list unmodified.

Comment: so, if it was like: first.add(WM.get())) and second.add(WM.get(0)) they are not actually pointing to the same element?

Comment: They are pointing to the same object, e.g. a Person object in my example, but the array (`WM`) and the two lists (`first`, `second`) are three distinct collections that all contain the same object. Changing one of the collections (add/remove) will not modify the other two.

Comment: Does, "all contain the same object" not mean, "they are going to work on the same object?" I thought thats the point of using reference. Can you suggest me, anything other than linkedlist(if it's not working) how can I achieve that memory dependency?? "changing one will change all? Since they are sharing/ponting to the same object?" THANKS!

Comment: I think you are confusing the list (array or linked) with the object. They all reference the same object, so if you change the object (e.g. change name like my example), all the lists will see it, but adding or removing an object from one of the lists is a list change, not an object change, so the other lists won't reflect that. Why have multiple lists if you want them all to be equal?

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I understand it perfectly now. By deleting an element from WM, i was actually changing WM. but WM was pointing the object which remains same to others. I changed the code. used: WM.set(1, new_input) to replace the 2nd object's value. it is changing the WM, but first and second( the other lists) are not 'seeing' it. they remain the same. Could you please explain? I think this time, I changed the value of the actual object!

Comment: Nope, you replaced the second element of `WM` with another object, again changing `WM`. The other lists are still referencing the original object.

Comment: WOW! Then how can I access the original object and change its value? Should I just declare a simple class holding a string and use it's own method to change the value? Thanks. I appreciate your replies.

Comment: If your list item is a `String`, then yeah, you'll need a `StringHolder` (or whatever you prefer to call it).