# Footer still active after reading it (rtf formular file)

Tags: c#, ms-word, footer, rtf

An rtf document is generated by a data base application, with information from this data base. I have created a software  (C#, net framework 4.5), to pick up data, then to record it into Excel file.

I have to read the footer of the rtf file, thing I can do.

But, when software access to footer, the document view is the same when footer/header are active (the same effect when you double click on header/footer to access it when you are under Word. This action action adds a carriage return on header (Word add this to enter something), and this \r causes to have additional page.

Here the code :

```
Sections oSection = cGlobalVar.varWordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections;
HeaderFooter oFooter = oSection[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage];

Range oRange = oFooter.Range.Tables[1].Range;//<= at this point, footer is accessible, the empty header of original document has a\r character, causing 2nd page to document that I don't want

strBuffer = oRange.Text;//<= information I need

oRange = oSection[1].Range.Tables[1].Range;//<= try to affect something else to oRange
oFooter = null;//<= try to null the object
oSection = null;//<= same as above

//cGlobalVar.varWordDoc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = WdViewType.wdPrintView;//<= try to use this to return to a normal state
```

I have tried to manipulate Word to find something to get back to my original document (one page), but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Nulling the object won't clear its content. If you want to clear it, change the text of the range object

```
oFooter.Range.Text = "";
oSection.Range.Text = "";
```

Note: These objects have a reference type. This means that the variable points to the actual object, which is somewhere else. If you set the variable to null, you are just loosing the link to the object, but you are not changing the object. See my answer to the SO question [Setting a type reference type to null doesn't affect copied type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8069712/880990)

---

**UPDATE**

I made an experiment in Word, using a VBA macro that reads the table range of the footer as you did above. It does not change the view type of word.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim oSection As Sections
    Dim oFooter As HeaderFooter
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim strBuffer As String

    Set oSection = Application.ActiveDocument.Sections
    Set oFooter = oSection(1).Footers(WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
    Set oRange = oFooter.Range.Tables(1).Range

    strBuffer = oRange.Text
    Debug.Print strBuffer
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it under VBA, and it works. Now, using the COM, still get trouble unless I have changed Word2003 to Word2010