# Reference to a reference in C#

Tags: c#, reference

Supose I create a variable B that references another one, A, both of them being reference type variables. If I set B or A to null, the other one would still be pointing to the object instance, that would remain untouched.

```
SomeClass A = new SomeClass();
SomeClass B = A;
B = null;                       //A still has a valid reference
```

This is also true:

```
SomeClass A = new SomeClass();
SomeClass B = A;
A = null;                       //B still has a valid reference
```

But I don´t want B to reference the instance referenced by A, I want B to reference A itself. That way, if B was set to null, A would be set to null as well. Is there any elegant, safe(no pointers) way of doing this? or am I trying to do something that is against C# principles?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use only one variable then ?

Comment: Think about variables as records in phone book. If you have two records with same value (i.e. address of SomeClass variable) then you can clear one of records and other will have original value.

Comment: "am I trying to do something that is against C# principles?" - I would think so, yes. The address pointing to the real object is copied by value and not by reference. You *might* be able to achieve what you want with pointers, but you're probably trying to solve the wrong problem with this. - Why do you need to set `A` to null via `B`?

Comment: Both first questions are possibly right. But what if I have to use pass an instance between classes and then I delete it in one of them? What would be the clever way of clearing all the references? Possibly the problem is in my design, though...

Comment: @Gerard I guess, you misunderstand `null` here. When variable assigned to `null` it means that it does not point any valid object on the heap. That (assigning `null` to variable) has nothing to with objects itself.

Comment: @Gerard possibly if you provide more code, you get more help

Comment: @Gerard, you don't clear managed memory, the garbage collector does it for you, some time after there are no more references. If your class uses unmanaged memory or other classes that implement `IDisposable` then it should implement `IDisposable` and probably a deconstructor.

Comment: @Gerard maybe your object should have some sort of `IsActive` or `IsDisposed` boolean value, or you should be using a single property/field instead of having different references to your object. If you give us more details about why you want this, I think a better solution will be clear.

Comment: You *could* make a `Wrapper<T>` class with a property `T Value`. Now you can pass the wrapper object around. And if one method sets the `Value` to null, all the other users of the wrapper object will also see the `Value` set to null.

Comment: @Corak How's that different from having _shared_ variable? :)

Comment: @Leri - you mean static? One can pass the wrapper between different classes and also different objects of one class can have different wrapper values.

Comment: I don´t think I should edit the question because it could be clarifying to other people as it is. But I´ll comment it here: I have a lot of data, I also have a table in which I show part of the data, let´s say I filter it by date. In the table I would be able to edit the data, so the user could delete any data cell but how then am I suposed to delete the same information in the original data list? Should I use a static data list?

Comment: The method that deletes the data item in filtered view could also call some kind of delete method on the original data list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this the way you would do it in C++ or C. The only time you can have a reference to an object handle is when you call a method with a `ref` parameter: viz:

```
void main_method()
{
    SomeClass A = new SomeClass();
    secondary_method(ref A);
}

void secondary_method(ref SomeClass B)
{
    B = null;   // this has the side effect of clearing the A of main_method
}
```

Comment: @X.L.Ant yes, but what the OP meant doesn't exist in the language

Comment: @MarcGravell Agreed :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is for neither of those variables to directly refer to the object, but to instead refer to an object instance that has a field pointing to an actual `SomeClass` instance:

```
public class Pointer<T>
{
    public T Value {get;set;}
}
```

---

```
Pointer<SomeClass> A = new Pointer<SomeClass>(){ Value = new SomeClass()};
Pointer<SomeClass> B = A;
B.Value = null;    
//A.Value is null
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has the following definition for a reference type: "*Variables of reference types store references to the actual data*" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In your case, setting the second variable to null is only causing the reference of the second variable to be broken without having any effect on the actual data. This is clearly shown in the post by Olivier available at [Setting a type reference type to null doesn't affect copied type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069396/setting-a-type-reference-type-to-null-doesnt-affect-copied-type).

A possible solution to your problem is to make use of a **WeakReference**.

According to MSDN: "*A weak reference allows the garbage collector to collect an object while still allowing an application to access the object. If you need the object, you can still obtain a strong reference to it and prevent it from being collected*" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So as long as the second (local) reference is accessing your weak reference, the object won't be garbage collected. Once you break the local reference by setting that to null, the GC would clear the weakly referenced object. More information on WeakReference is available at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247.aspx