# Recursion, can't make nested self object null, why is it so?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I am trying to update a list of self object in recursive code but it not doing, but when update the object by changing the values is working fine!

[image: here is attached image for the output]

```cs
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Node main = new Node();
            main.Sequence = "1";
            main.Id = 1;

            main.ChildNodes.Add(new Node()
            {
                Sequence = "1.1",
                Id = 2
            });
            main.ChildNodes.Add(new Node()
            {
                Sequence = "1.2",
                Id = 3
            });
            main.ChildNodes.Add(new Node()
            {
                Sequence = "1.3",
                Id = 4
            });
            Console.WriteLine("Before :");
            PrintNode(main);
            Console.WriteLine();
            MakeNull(main);

            Console.WriteLine("After :");
            PrintNode(main);

            void MakeNull(Node node)
            {
                foreach (var Child in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    MakeNull(Child);
                }
                node.ChildNodes.RemoveAll(p => p == null);
                if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
                {
                    node.Id = 5;//this is working 
                    node = null;//this is not, why ?
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static void PrintNode(Node node)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id:" + node.Id + " Sequence:" + node.Sequence);
            for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                PrintNode(node.ChildNodes[i]);
            }
        }


    }
    public class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Sequence { get; set; }
        public List<Node> ChildNodes { get; set; }
        public Node()
        {
            ChildNodes = new List<Node>();
        }

    }
}
```

why it is not make whole object null?

Comment: whats the point of setting an objects property if you then set that object to null??

Comment: Are you trying to make an `IDisposable`-like object?

Comment: Setting the variable to null only affects that local variable (a parameter in that case). It does absolutely nothing to the outside of that function. Maybe you want to look into `ref` parameters?

Comment: @Liam setting property is just for demo purpose, actually i need to make it null but couldn't

Comment: @Alejandro while i am updating its property its working fine but when is come to making it null it wont work why is it so ?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is just to "play around", and far from a real world scenario. In the real world, you would just delete the child elements if they are big, or simply stop using them and the garbage collector will free the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what happens, it is crucial to know that a class is a reference type. I.e., variables of this type contain either `null` or a reference to an object. They do not contain the object itself or the values stored in this object.

This is different from a value type like `int`. A variable of this type effectively contains the number it represents.

---

In `void MakeNull(Node node)`, the parameter `node` holds a copy of the reference passed to it (because it is passed by value, i.e., without the `ref` or `in` or `out` keyword). You are only settings this copy to `null`. If you want to set the variable of the caller to `null`, you must pass it by reference:

```
void MakeNull(ref Node node)
{
    ...
    node = null;
    ...
}
```

Call it with

```
MakeNull(ref main);
```

or

```
MakeNull(ref Child);
```

Now, `node` is not a copy of the caller's variable but an alias of it. E.g., when you call

```
MakeNull(ref main);
```

... `node` is just another name for `main`. Setting `node = null;` now effectively sets `main = null;`.

Why does it work for `node.Id = 5;` then? Because `node` holds a reference to a `Node` object, and thus, the `Id` of this object is changed. Note that in your implementation you have a copy of a reference to a `Node` object in `node`, not a copy of the object itself.

See also my answer to this SO question: [Setting a type reference type to null doesn't affect copied type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8069396/880990)

Answer (score 2):

Because within your method MakeNull(Node node), node becomes a reference within that scope holding the 'main' object from the calling function. Setting node to null within the function, will only have as effect that you set the node reference to null within that method. The reference to 'main' is lost (overwritten by null).

That does not mean that 'main' outside of that MakeNull(Node node) method becomes null.

Setting Id does work, because you set the Id before overwriting the node reference with null. At this point, node still references to 'main' and we can get a reference to the setter of Id and then setting its value.

If you want to make the item of the list null, you have to do something like: main[i] = null.

Others have pointed out that using the ref keyword should do the trick, but this is only true for MakeNull(main). Not for the child items. With what you are doing you might expect to see a list of 'null' child items (e.g. calling ChildItem[1] and then expecting to see 'null'). But this is not the case.

See the code snippet below for an example of what will happen:

```
            List<Bla> a = new List<Bla>();

            a.Add(new Bla());
            a.Add(new Bla());
            a.Add(new Bla());

            void MakeNull(ref Bla a) { a = null; }

            var a1 = a[1];

            MakeNull(ref a1);
            // MakeNull(ref a[1]);              // not allowed by compiler
            // MakeNull(ref a.ElementAt(1));    // not allowed by compiler

            Console.WriteLine(a1); // prints nothing (null)
            Console.WriteLine(a[1]); // prints "Core.App.Bla"
```

You can fix this like by using a lambda action that references the actual indexer method or another setter method **on the collection**:

```
            void MakeNullAction(Action<Bla> setter) { setter(null); }

            MakeNullAction((value) => a[1] = value);

            Console.WriteLine(a[1]); // prints nothing (null)
```

Comment: Making null is job of MakeNull() function and in this node is referencing the main object..

this is working 
 node.Id = 5;

but this is not 
node = null; 

why is it so ?

Comment: I edited my post to explain it more briefly

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a function parameter as a reference type, the value is passed to the function *by reference*. What that means is that when you declare a method parameter as type `Node`, you will get a copy of a pointer to the same memory location as you passed into the method, you are not actually passing the object itself.

```
        void MakeNull(Node node) // <-- This is a new variable that points to the same memory location as the variable that was passed in
        {
            foreach (var Child in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                MakeNull(Child);
            }
            node.ChildNodes.RemoveAll(p => p == null);
            if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
            {
                node.Id = 5;
                node = null;
            }
        }
```

The scope of the variable `node` is constrained only to the method, since the method parameter is where it is declared. When you set it to `null` within the method, you are only destroying the pointer to the `node` memory location *inside* of the method, but the one that you *passed into* the method remains intact, since it had been copied when you called the method.

> why it is not make whole object null ?

In short, because an *object* cannot be set to *null*. Only the object pointer (the variable) can. And you are dealing with 2 separate object pointers of type `Node`, one inside of the method and one outside of the method.

Setting the `node` variable inside of the method to `null` only destroys the pointer that you created at the beginning of the method. When you had a reference to the memory location, and you updated its `Id` property to `5`, you were working with the object itself, not the object pointer.